# Making a ring out of shapes in P5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want to make a ring out of circles in P5.js.
I want the circles to have the same size between each other and completing the ring, but the amount of the circles can be changed to any value.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 13; i++){
    xCircle = middle + cos(i/3) * 200;
    yCircle = middle - sin(i/3) * 200;
}
```

This only starts the ring but isnt completing it. And I know that somewhere has to be the number of total amount of circles but I don't know where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The angle of a full circle in radians is 2*PI = 6,2836... .
You've do divide the angle of a full circle by the number of parts (circles) and to multiply it by the index (`i`) of the circle.

e.g

```js
middle = // ...
circleRadius = // ...

circles = 13;
angle = Math.PI*2 / circles;

for(var i = 0; i < circles; i++){

    xCircle = middle + cos(angle*i) * 200;
    yCircle = middle - sin(angle*i) * 200;

    ellipse(xCircle, yCircle, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2);
}
```

---

If you want to use degrees rather than radians, then the angle mode can be switched to degrees by [`angleMode()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/angleMode).
the angle of a full circle is 360 degrees:

```js
angleMode(DEGREES); 

circles = 13;
angle = 360 / circles;

for(var i = 0; i < circles; i++){

    xCircle = middle + cos(angle*i) * 200;
    yCircle = middle - sin(angle*i) * 200;

    ellipse(xCircle, yCircle, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2);
}
```

---

If you wan to draw "touching" circles which form a circular shape, then the radius of one circle (`circleRadius`) can be calculated by `sin(angle/2) * radius`, where  `radius`  is the radius of the circular shape:

```js
circles = 13;
angle = Math.PI*2 / circles;

radius = 200;
circleRadius = sin(angle/2) * radius;
```

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(250, 250);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    fill(0);
    stroke(255, 0, 0)
    strokeWeight(2);

    middle = width/2;

    circles = 13;
    angle = Math.PI*2 / circles;

    radius = 100;
    circleRadius = sin(angle/2) * radius;

    for(var i = 0; i < circles; i++){

        xCircle = middle + cos(angle*i) * radius;
        yCircle = middle - sin(angle*i) * radius;

        ellipse(xCircle, yCircle, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.js"></script>
```